# Why Does SynchronousQueue not Implement TransferQueue?

Tags: java, concurrency

In Java, `SynchronousQueue` looks like it might be able to implement `TransferQueue`.  I see TransferQueue was added later, but I was wondering why SynchronousQueue was not adapted to implement it?

Comment: Best place to ask was [concurrency-interest](https://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/), but as that is down due to university server failure, you could ask on [core-libs-dev](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/core-libs-dev/) or email Doug.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are multiple reasons for this:

- different concept of the queues. `SynchronousQueue` assumes that there's exactly one consumer in one thread and exactly one consumer in another thread synching up an object. `TransferQueue` is designed more as message-passing tool with multiple conumers/producers
- backward compatibility: suppose we have serialized an instance of `SynchronousQueue` using Java 6 and written the bytes somewhere. Now we are taking them out and deserializing on Java 8. If some fields were added to `SynchronousQueue` in order to implement new methods of `TransferQueueu` how can we guarantee correct deserialization?
- `SynchronousQueue` is fully blocking queue while `TransferQueue` provides non-blocking methods as well
- JavaDoc of `SynchronousQueue` claims:

```java
A synchronous queue does not have any
 * internal capacity, not even a capacity of one.  You cannot
 * {@code peek} at a synchronous queue because an element is only
 * present when you try to remove it; you cannot insert an element
 * (using any method) unless another thread is trying to remove it;
 * you cannot iterate as there is nothing to iterate.
```

i.e. this a queue without capacity. Compare with description of `TransferQueue`:

```java
* Like other blocking queues, a {@code TransferQueue} may be
* capacity bounded
```

So both they seem to be pretty different.